# Is there a naming convention for a navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

When I try to push a view controller to my UINavigationController I get a NSInvalidArgumentException thrown with the error message "unrecognized selector sent to instance".  But this only happens when I name my UINavigationController ivar anything other than "navigationController".  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: ok I narrowed it down.  Can someone explain to me why I need to use:
[self navigationController] pushViewController:...  when my UINavigationController ivar is named "nav" in my AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your code is structured, but every `UIViewController` has a `navigationController` property.  (See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

So, `[self navigationController]` is returning the property from the current view controller (whatever `self` is), not what you've named in your AppDelegate.